# In Rails/Formtastic how do I restrict hours in the time input field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, formtastic

I have a requirement to display duration as HH:MM in Rails  as two select boxes one for hours and other for minutes. Restrict the hours to max of 4:00. 'duration'(column type:integer) is stored as minutes in database.
And I am using formtastic.

If I dispaly input as time, I am able to get the output format as drop down HH:MM.

"<%= f.input :duration,      :label => 'Duration',    :as=>:time, :minute_step => 15, :hint=>"Measured in hours", :end => 10 %>"

How do I restrict the hours shown for selection( only 01, 02, 03, 04 should be displayed in the drop down for hours)?

Please let me know if there are any options to be specified for Rails/Formtastic. Or is there any better way to handle this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any options to limit it through Formtastic. You could just display the input as a select and pass it the options you want explicitly.

```
<%= f.input :hours, :as=>:select, :collection => (0..4) %>
<%= f.input :minutes, :as=>:select, :collection => [0,15,30,45] %>
```

Then you'll probably need to add these virtual attributes in the model:

```
before_save :set_duration

def set_duration
  self.duration = @hours * 60 + @minutes
end

def hours
  self.duration / 60;
end

def minutes
  self.duration % 60;
end

def hours=(h)
  @hours = h
end

def minutes=(m)
 @minutes = m
end

def duration=(d)
  @hours = d / 60
  @minutes = d % 60
  self.set_duration
end
```

And you might want to look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2178991/include-two-inputs-in-same-li-element-in-formtastic) to get them to look more like the original.

There might be some clever, quicker way to do this, but this is the first thing that comes to mind.

Comment: Thanks for solution. I would like to display as two select boxes, one for hours and one for mins.

Comment: Ah, missed that. Edited my answer.

Comment: Not sure if this works everytime.For instance if the minute setter gets called after hours setter then we would have wrong information stored in duraion

Comment: `code`def hours=(h)
  self.hours = h;
end;
def minutes=(m)
 self.minutes = m;
end;                                                                 def set_duration
    self.duration = self.hours + self.minutes; 
end;
`code`                                                              Add set_duration as before_save callback.

Comment: Good point. Edited answer do to use that method and fixed your small error.

Comment: Luke, I am sorry the above would not work as self.minutes = m is running into a loop. I get a stack level too deep error

Comment: I am not sure of using instance variables as in the above case if we want to set duration directly duration = 65 it might not work. So better use write_attribute and read_attribute
`code`  def hours=(h)
    #self[:hours] = h.to_i * 60
    write_attribute(:hours, h.to_i)
  end ;   def set_duration
    write_attribute(:duration , read_attribute(:hours) * 60  + read_attribute(:minutes))
  end;
  def minutes=(m)
    write_attribute(:minutes, m.to_i)
  end; `code`.

Comment: Except the model doesn't actually have hour and minute attributes. I'm not sure if ActiveRecord would complain about that or not. I edited my answer with a possible fix.

Comment: I am not sure, how Active Record makes use of instance variables so I am bit hesitant to use instance variables.