# Display inline in Formtastic Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, formtastic

I am using Formtastic for rendering a Form, and would like to display the inputs inline. For example,

> "Enter Your Email"  "Email Text Box" "Enter The Password" "Password Text Box" "SIGN UP BUTTON"

I tried the solution suggested at [Include two inputs in same LI element in Formtastic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2178991/include-two-inputs-in-same-li-element-in-formtastic) , but the form rendered is skewed. To be specific, The Labels (Enter Email, Enter Password) are rendered together, side by side, followed by the Text Boxes, although they all appear in the same line.

> "Enter Your Email" "Enter The Password" "Email Text Box" "Password Text Box"

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Can you not just use CSS to display the list horizontally using something like this?

[Horizontal List CSS](http://css.maxdesign.com.au/listutorial/horizontal_master.htm)

That size suggests that you should just use

```
 ul li { 
     display: inline; 
 }
```

Comment: Thats exactly what I have done, but no success:

form.formtastic fieldset ol li.fl {display:inline;}

I guess formtastic is over-riding it from behind. I cannot get any hints from Inspect Element too.

Comment: Where is the .fl class coming from?  Is that on all your formtastic list elements?  Have you tried without that?

Comment: 'fl' is the html-wrapper class over every form input that I want to be rendered inline. No, I am not using it anywhere else.

Comment: Are you able to post the HTML for the form and also tell me what Inspect Element says the computed style is for display please?

Comment: thanks for your help, actually the problem was with the foundation framework, it was over-riding the CSS.