# How to show two 'f.input' in one line in activeadmin form page

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

```
form do |f|
    f.inputs :question do
        f.input :id, :as => :hidden
        f.input :questionaire_id, :as => :hidden
        f.input :role, :as => :hidden
        f.input :question_type
        f.input :description
        f.input :option
        f.input :score
    end
    f.actions
end
```

In above form, how to show this two inputs

```
        f.input :option
        f.input :score
```

in one line? Any idea?

Comment: @AndreyDeineko sorry for being so late~

Answer (score 4):

I think I got the answer

First we should check this [Formtastic::Helpers::InputHelper](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/justinfrench/formtastic/Formtastic/Helpers/InputHelper)

According to the helper:

**input** is used to render all content (labels, form widgets, error messages, hints, etc) for a single form input (or field), usually representing a single method or attribute on the form's object or model.

The content is wrapped in an **li** tag, so it's usually called inside an inputs block (which renders an **ol** inside a **fieldset**).

It's option **:wrapper_html** can be used to override or add to the HTML attributes to be passed down to the wrapping **li** tag

So in the form we should do this:

```
form do |f|
f.inputs :question do
    f.input :id, :as => :hidden
    f.input :questionaire_id, :as => :hidden
    f.input :role, :as => :hidden
    f.input :question_type
    f.input :description
    f.input :option, :wrapper_html => { :class => 'fl' } 
    f.input :score, :wrapper_html => { :class => 'fl' }, :label => false
end
f.actions
end
```

**:label => false** can disabled the label of form input.

And then specify the class **'fl'** in the css file(I just add following css from [Include two inputs in same LI element in Formtastic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2178991/include-two-inputs-in-same-li-element-in-formtastic) in active_admin.css.scss like @Andrey Deineko told):

```
form.formtastic fieldset ol li.fl {display:inline;}
```

Then we have two inputs on the same line~Hope this will be helpful~

Comment: Not working on rails 7 ruby 3